# return single value with multiple variance

Tags: python

I have a table that has this value:

```
Id   Name                  Description
1   (Red) Mazda             Nice
2    Ferrari                Super Nice
3   (Black) Mazda           Nice
4    Mazda                  Nice
```

I am returning them like this:

```
for row in all_cars:
     rows_as_dict = {
         "id": row.id,
         "car": {
             "name": row.name,
             "description": row.description,
         }
     }
     all_cars.append(rows_as_dict)
```

How could I make it such that I could return this in a such a way that if there is variance of car it should look like this:

```
res = [{
     "id" : "4",
     "cars" : {
            "name": "Mazda",
            "description": "Nice",
            "variance": [
                "Red",
                "Black"
      ]},{
     "id" : "2",
     "cars" : {
            "name": "Ferrari",
            "description": "Super Nice",
            "variance": [
            ]
     }]
```

Comment: how do you get `1322` ?

Comment: The naive approach would be extract the car name (minus the variance) and iterate through ```all_cars```, checking each car's name. If the name matches, add the variance to that car's variance array.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't double check my post. I have edited it to be clearer.

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list while you're interating over it.

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? A SQL table? A pandas DataFrame? A txt file?

Comment: It's easier if you make the result a dictionary whose keys are the car names, minus the variance, rather than a list. If you really want a list you can use `result.items()` at the end.

Comment: @Dan A sql table.

Comment: @LearningNoob please include the code you are using to read this into python

Comment: What if two rows have the same name and different variance but also different description? For example, what if you had `1   (Red) Mazda             Nice`  and `3   (Black) Mazda           Super Nice` what would you expect the output to be? You did not specifiy.

Comment: @Dan I am using sqlalchemy to get this. Just a simple Cars.query.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = '''
Id   Name                  Description
1   (Red) Mazda             Nice
2    Ferrari                Super Nice
3   (Black) Mazda           Nice
4    Mazda                  Nice'''

import re
from collections import defaultdict
import json

tbl = [*re.findall(r'^(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s{2,}(.*)$', data, flags=re.M)]

variances = defaultdict(list)
out = {}
for (id_, name, desc) in tbl:
    g = re.match(r'^(?:\(([^)]+)\))?\s*(.*)', name).groups()
    if g[0]:
        variances[g[1]].append(g[0])
    out[g[1]] = {
         "id": id_,
         "car": {
             "name": g[1],
             "description": desc,
         }
     }

for k, v in out.items():
    out[k]['variance'] = variances[k]

print(json.dumps([*out.values()], indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "id": "4",
        "car": {
            "name": "Mazda",
            "description": "Nice"
        },
        "variance": [
            "Red",
            "Black"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "car": {
            "name": "Ferrari",
            "description": "Super Nice"
        },
        "variance": []
    }
]
```